React app/Fast API : How to trigger EC2 Turn off/ Turn on using AWS Lambda and keep their IP static?
I have two EC2 instances .
One instance runs a React APP.
Another instance runs a Fast API.
Currently deployment process is (completely  manual):

Turn on the Fast API Ec2 Instance,
Get the public IP of that instance from AWS console
Add the IP to React App config code (manually update URL in the code)
Run the React APP ec2 instance.

I am trying to automate this process using AWS Lambda.
Idea is to :

Run a manual lambda trigger which turns on the Fast API ec2 instance
Lambda gets the IP of the Fast API ec2
Automatically updates the IP on React APP config URL code
Turns on the React App ec2 instance.

Question is :
Is there a better approach? I mean to put Fast API and react in two separate docker containers in the same ec2 instance?
Is there any way to attach the back end IP to the react app instead of updating the url in the code ?

Why do you need a new EC2 instance every time you deploy? And the React application should be just static html files you can stuff in S3 for far cheaper - and in both cases, Cloudfront can be put in front of them to have a lasting hostname for both.
